# Let $f(x)=\frac{1-2x^2}{1+x^2} (x\in \mathbb{R})$. Find its Chebyshev norm $||f||_\infty$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x)=\frac{1-2x^2}{1+x^2} (x\in \mathbb{R})$. Find its Chebyshev norm $||f||_\infty$

I'm not to sure how to go about answering this question, I think the way to go by answering it is finding the supremum of $|f(x)|$?

Comment: yes exactly....

Comment: Hint: $f(x)=\frac{3}{1+x^2}-2$.

Answer (score 0):

We have $|f(x)| \to 2$ for $x \to \pm \infty$ and $|f(x)| \le 2$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$.

It is your turn to verify this inequality !

Conclusion: $||f||_\infty=2$.

Comment: $f(x)=\frac{3}{1+x^2}-2 \to -2$ as $x \to \pm \infty$, hence $|f(x)| \to 2$ as $x \to \pm \infty$,